# Getting the analytic expression for this equation?

Tags: integration, modular-arithmetic, analytic-functions

I need to find the analytic equation for the following expression:

$$a_n = \frac {1}{L}\int^L _{-L} 2x \ mod1 \ cos({\frac{n\pi}{L}}x) dx$$ in terms of n wherein n =1,2,3.

I attempted to tackle this question by integrating the equation and then finding some way to separate n, but then the mod gets in the way as I don't know how to handle that. Also, once I manage that, I'm not too sure how to separate n from there.

Does anyone have any ideas please? Especially with that pesky mod?

Comment: Is the mod here supposed to mean fractional part?

Comment: I am honestly not so sure, but I assumed that it meant modulus.
That's another problem of mine, I can't get anywhere with this since I don't know how to use it.